# What is the best way to export LWC and import third party LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm from Angular background and would like to know if there is a seamless way to import LWC-based third party components in LWC. I would like to create "dumb" components that I can import in different projects and use them as I please. What we currently do is, we have a private git repo where we have reusable components then, "copy-paste" the components that we need in the project where we need them. The problem is, some of the components reference other custom components which means we need to "copy-paste" those components as well. If this will become harder to track as the package becomes larger.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this blog post](https://medium.com/slalom-technology/anatomy-of-an-enterprise-sfdx-project-30cdbfbad00a) about how you can structure SFDX projects to create separate source trees for "feature modules" and how the [SFDX Falcon](https://sfdx-isv.github.io/sfdx-falcon/index.html) template can help the developer organize their metadata to achieve what you want to do.

Worth noting that you could package the components using a second generation managed package, though in this case you can't then use them within custom components developed outside the package (you can't currently refer to [custom LWC components from other namespaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/create_components_namespace)) and can only use them through the Lightning App Builder (assuming they are exposed).